# Reading keywords from a file and searching for them without results

Tags: c#, encoding, character, streamreader

I use this code of C# for reading from the keywords.txt. where i have stored some keywords and phrases in 4-5 languages (Greek, Swedish, Turkish etc)

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("keywords.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
ArrayList keywords = new ArrayList();
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    keywords.Add(sr.ReadLine());
}
sr.Close();
```

Afterwards i use this one

```
string comment = getText(rev, "comment=&quot;", "&quot;", out rev);
if (comment.Contains(keywords[i].ToString()))
{
    blah blah blah
}
```

It can read english words but not greek, turkish with special chars etc.. I have used the default encoding UTF8 no result.. i have changed the encoding of streamread to unicode no result..
Do you have any ideas?
Thanks :D

UPDATE: I found out that the problem is when getText gets the comment and not when i compare the keywords with the comment.. I saved the comments to a file

```
string comment = getText(rev, "comment=&quot;", "&quot;", out rev);
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("WriteText.txt", true))
    {
        file.WriteLine(comment);
    }
```

and i got this kind of symbols instead of greek letters

```
Ξ‘Ξ½Ξ±Ξ―ΟΞµΟƒΞ· Ξ­ΞΊΞ΄ΞΏΟƒΞ·Ο‚ 4232870 Ξ±Ο€Ο Ο„ΞΏΞ½
```

With a small research and testing i found out that this is the same Greek content with encoding set to Windows 1253.. Is there any way to control the encoding the getText uses?

Comment: Which part is not working?

Comment: It comes into play! [The Turkish Problem](http://thinkingcsharp.blogspot.com/2009/01/turkish-i-problem-why-my-application.html)

Comment: Despite the fact that the keywords i am searching exists, the program does not seem to be able to understand it...
It is not only with turkish words but also with greek, frence, czech, hugarian etc.. If there is a special character (αβω, ί, á, í, ř, ğ, ş) that does not exist in English language then we have a problem...

Comment: Is it possible that you destroy the `rev` in `getText`. strange usage: `getText(rev, ... , ... , out rev);`

Comment: It works fine this way with english words... Do you have something special in mind?

Comment: Lets say something similar... i want to do this one... but it fails.. there are many "Άλφα" in my text but it finds zero..   if ((comment.Contains("Άλφα")))

                    {

                        blah blah
                    
}

Comment: @JimKlouvas As I said in my previous comment. Does `getText` work correctly. Can you post its code? Better, Post a self-contained, complete and small code that demonstrates your problem. Otherwise, I don't think we can help you..

Comment: @I4V you are right.. i have updated my first post.. the problem is in getText encodind.. my code is quite big so it is difficult to get one complete piece.. if you insist that it will be helpful i dont have a problem

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is because the keyword and the comment are similar strings but not equal (uppercase/lowercase, culture specific words) you have to use another version of compare:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc190529.aspx

```
public static int Compare(
    string strA,
    int indexA,
    string strB,
    int indexB,
    int length,
    CultureInfo culture,
    CompareOptions options
```

Where the last parameter CompareOptions will be something like: IgnoreSymbols | IgnoreCase | IgnoreNonSpace

Comment: The keyword and the comment seem exactly the same... But i think there is a difference in their encoding and this is why my program does not recognize them as the same..
I am testing for greek words or even characters (lets say "α" ) and doesnt find any despite the fact that there are many exaclty the same..

Comment: c# getText is not a c# standard function (at least, I don't know about this instruction). Can you put the code of this function?  And change the System.Text.Encoding.Unicode to UTF8!

Comment: The encoding is only to save and retrieve the information to/from disk (must be writeeng and read in the same encoding!), in memory, in a c# string, the information is stored in the same codification (UTF8 I think). I think that the problem is the compare. Did you use the version of Compare that I gave you?

Comment: I have found a lame solution.. I found how my program read the greek words (something like this Ξ‘Ξ½Ξ±Ξ―ΟΞµΟƒΞ·) and i used this kind of words to compare.. and it worked.. it is lame, you have to see every single word how it is written in this weird encoding but it works.. thanks everybody..

Comment: I think that is the gettext... please, can you provide the namespace or what is the implementation?